# How can we automate CLI (Command Line Interface) in java?

Tags: java, automated-tests

Can we automate CLI (Command Line Interface) in java?
Please suggest how to achieve it.
Basically I need to read the commands from the excel file one by one, execute them in Java and copy the output results.

Comment: show us what you mean - post what you have tried so far

Comment: I only tried to execute the basic example for Ping command ---  Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec("ping 192.168.0.30");

       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
       InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
       String inputLine;
       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
       in.close();

Comment: Check this tutorial https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to create process.

For tutorial refer [this](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/processbuilder/java-lang-processbuilder-example/).

For e.g.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("echo", "Echo Example");
Process process = pb.start();
\\you can use the process.getInputStream() to get the console output.
```

Comment: If your link goes stale, then this answer is no better than a comment

Comment: I beg your pardon.

Comment: *For tutorial refer this.*  How about including key points here

Comment: With all due respect, I didn't add much because the tutorial covers most in the best possible way. Thus, writing the same thing here won't make much sense. I will keep this in mind in future though. Thanks.

Comment: and my point is if javacodegeeks move or delete that article your link will be broken and useless

Comment: That's actually true. My bad. I am updating my answer. Thanks. :)